# laravel email detects profanity words

Tags: php, laravel, email, marketplace

I was wondering if there's a laravel package available to detect profanity, breach of terms of conditions in emails.

I am building a freelance website. The employer should have the ability to contact the worker directly. However, when they email each other and if the system detects that the employer is providing full email address, a warning will then be raised that they might be breaching terms and conditions.

If there's profanity, it will also raise a flag to investigate.

Thanks

Comment: http://banbuilder.com/  php package you could probably use to detect profanity

Comment: ok thanks, i will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply detect profanities on the string with [WTFilter](https://github.com/kaankilic/wtfilter) for Laravel. It's highly fluent for the Laravel project because of the language based profanity detection system.